# Extract the data from ViewBag at base ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

```
public class GeneralFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        dynamic val = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;
        string action = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
        string controller = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am passing data from controller actions through viewbag. i am able to see those data at above mentioned variable val. how to extract the data from the variable **dynamic val** in the above code?!

when i browse with break point this is the flow

- val {System.Web.Mvc.DynamicViewDataDictionary}

  - ViewData {System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary}
  - _innerDictionary Count = 1

    - [0]  => My Required Data is here  <=
      or
  - Values Count = 1

    - [0]  => My Required Data is here  <=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my controller, if i pass data like this

`var Numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };`

`ViewBag.numbers = Numbers;`

then i can fetch the data from CustomfilterAttribute like this

`foreach (var number in filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.numbers)`

`{`
`var i = number;`
`}`

Note: for this you need to assign the [GeneralFilter] only for methods which pass data of ViewBag.numbers else you have to face null reference error!
i Appreciate for other better answers for this!?

Comment: to avoid null reference error simply put an if condition  like this   "if(filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.numbers !=null)"   it works for me! any better ans?